# NestJS - Use multiple MongoDB connections per module

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, multiple-databases

Is there a way to connect multiple MongoDB connections per module?

app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/masterDB'),
    UserModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Similarly, can we define another connection in another module which is a child of app.module?

child.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/childDB'),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'child', schema: ChildSchema }]),
  ],
  controllers: [ChildController],
  providers: [ChildService],
})
export class ChildModule { }
```

Or any other way to access different databases at once.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do it manually you have to use a providers file:

**mongoose.providers.ts**

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const mongooseProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'MASTER_CONNECTION',
    useFactory: (): Promise<typeof mongoose> =>
    // This mongoose.connect never working for multples DB connection
    // mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/masterDB'),
    // Following is working fine and tested by me
    mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/masterDB'),
  },
  {
    provide: 'CHILD_CONNECTION',
    useFactory: (): Promise<typeof mongoose> =>
    // This mongoose.connect never working for multples DB connection
    // mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/masterDB'),
    // Following is working fine and tested by me
      mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/ChildDB'),
  },
];
```

**mongoose.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { mongooseProviders } from './mongoose.providers';

@Module({
  providers: [...mongooseProviders],
  exports: [...mongooseProviders],
})
export class MongooseModule {}
```

**model.providers.ts**

```
import { Connection } from 'mongoose';
import { ChildSchema } from './schemas/child/child.schema';
import { MasterSchema } from './schemas/master/master.schema';

export const modelProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'CHILD_MODEL',
    useFactory: (connection: Connection) => connection.model('Child', ChildSchema),
    inject: ['CHILD_CONNECTION'],
  },
  {
    provide: 'MASTER_MODEL',
    useFactory: (connection: Connection) => connection.model('Master', MasterSchema),
    inject: ['MASTER_CONNECTION'],
  },
];
```

And on the constructor instead of using @InjectModel you use @Inject:

```
@Injectable
export Class ModelService {
  constructor(@Inject('MASTER_MODEL') private masterModel: Model<Master>) {}
...
```

**Note: in the module you provide the service you should import the MongooseModule and put as provider modelProviders.**

Comment: Hi, this seems the right answer to the question, ill mark it as "answered". But these providers are a singleton, right? Can we have a dynamic connections name? e.g. I may have multiple dynamic children (tenants) database - childDB1, childDB2, childDB3 ... and so on.

Comment: yes you can you will have to use a custom provider for each conection https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers take a look at this

Comment: hey, I think my above comment was not clear. I have a situation - I have users collection in my MasterDB and for each user registered in the app I need to create and use ChildDB dynamically e.g. user1 in MasterDB will have its own user1DB which can be accessed by some particular modules only. How can I update the MongoDB uri for each of those modules?

Comment: just change it in the mongoose.providers.ts in its factory

Answer (score 10):

[SOLVED March 2021]

Here you'll find the solution:

https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2020/04/nestjs-multiple-mongodb-databases.html

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { studentSchema } from './schemas/myworld/student.schema';
import { animalSchema } from './schemas/wildlife/animal.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: 'Student',
        schema: studentSchema,
        collection: 'Student',
        
      },
    ],'myWorldDb'),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: 'Animals',
        schema: animalSchema,
        collection: 'Animals'
      }
    ],'wildLifeDb'),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(
      'mongodb+srv://<userName>:<password>@cluster0-igk.mongodb.net/MyWorld?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
      {
        connectionName: 'myWorldDb'
      }
    ),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(
      'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-igk.mongodb.net/WildLife?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
      {
        connectionName: 'wildLifeDb'
      }
    )

  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Happy to be helpfull ^^

Comment: I get this error:
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TestService (?, AnimalsModel). Please make sure that the argument StudentModel at index [0] is available in the TestService context.
Do you know why?

Answer (score 4):

Post above from RalphJS really helped, but it only was using one connection for everything. Had to change 1 thing in **model.providers.ts**:
instead of `mongoose.connect`
you have to use `mongoose.createConnection`

## model.providers.ts

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const mongooseProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'MASTER_CONNECTION',
    useFactory: async (): Promise<unknown> =>
      await mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/masterDB'),
  },
  {
    provide: 'CHILD_CONNECTION',
    useFactory: async (): Promise<unknown> =>
      await mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/childDB'),
  },
];
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections